# Securing devices based on ownership

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-iot

Using the AWS cloud, we're trying to create a system that allows customers to manage IoT devices using mobile applications. Each user (from Cognito User Pools) will have at least one device. He will be able to send configurations and listen for status changes to each of these devices. We are currently thinking how to protect his devices from other users access.

So far, we were thinking about securing access to individual MQTT topics using "Customer managed policies". Each user would have a static policy authorizing him to specific topics. In case of ownership change, the policy would be updated. However, it seems like there is a limit of 1500 policies, which is lower than the expected number of users.

We would like the target solution to be flexible enough to allow a simple way to change the ownership of the device, without having to modify the configuration on the device side.